# PriorityQueue changes order when removing an element

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

Without providing custom comparator the priority queue inserts elements in ascending order, however, after removing a particular element the order is changed.

```java
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
pq.add(10);
pq.add(1);
pq.add(2);
pq.add(2);
    
pq.remove(2);
for(int x: pq) {
    System.out.println(x);
}

//outputs: 1 10 2, instead of expected: 1 2 10
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: To add on, the actual storage array backing `PriorityQueue` is essentially a heap/tree structure. Iterating that array (which is how the enhanced for-each evaluates here) will iterate the elements in order of their storage, not of how they're traversed over the heap. So to the average person, it's essentially an "unordered" array. But that does not mean the queue-related methods (like `#poll`, see below) are unordered.

Comment: The answer to this is right in the javadoc for PriorityQueue: "The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't iterate on your `PriorityQueue<T>` as you do on a collections/arrays; use `.poll()`, instead:

```java
while(pq.peek()!=null) {
    System.out.println(pq.poll());
}
```

Priority Queue is an Abstract Data Type, that is often implemented as a [Binary Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#:%7E:text=A%20binary%20heap%20is%20a,a%20data%20structure%20for%20heapsort.) data structure, which, in turn, is (commonly) implemented with the array.
<sub>There are some other ways to implement binary heap, but an ordinary array, is the fastest, simplest and best way for it.</sub>

An example of how the array represents a binary heap, looks like this:
[image]

Queue *order* is not being changed, in your case; rather, you're just utilizing data structure in a wrong way, by merely iterating on it in a traditional `for-each`/iterative way, as when you iterate on a basic array, not considering, that your Priority Queue backing array is not sorted with its i<sup>th</sup> index; rather it maintains the top element on top of tree (either Min Heap or Max Heap case) and you can't just get the `.poll()` effect by iterating on it in a traditional way.

Comment: Interesting. Even using iterator it shows it as `1 10 2`, any reason why the difference in output with `.poll()`?

Comment: See my comment to the question

Comment: Thank you, that explains it!

Comment: Maybe move that comment into your answer?

Comment: This is a good explanation of the chosen implementation, but the real answer here is that the public documentation for PriorityQueue answers the question (regardless of the chosen implementation): "The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order."

Comment: @jtahlborn well, that's exactly what I say here.. I'm just elaborating it a bit further.. to touch not only Java-specific implementation, but to give a more broad, bigger picture of the idea of the Priority Queue. So, the reason why iterator doesn't provide expected behaviour lies in the concept of the PQ. So, I can't really agree that this answer touches only Java *specifically* (chosen implementation).. on the contrary.

Comment: don't get me wrong, your answer is a nice explanation of why it does not work for the current impl. that said, i don't see what i said anywhere in your answer.  you could just as easily implement a PQ with a sorted list, in which case iteration _would_ be ordered.  but, you shouldn't _expect_ that behavior regardless of implementation because the javadoc explicitly states that no order is required on iteration.

Comment: @jtahlborn sorted list? and what happens when you add or remove element? you resort it everytime? that's not how usually PQs are implemented. The main benefit of the Binary Heap representation is that you have a very fast ( O(n) insertion and O(1) access) time complexity. Moreover, I even state in my answer, that it is ***often*** implemented as a Binary Heap.. but I don't say that it's always.. yet, still, Binary Heap is the best solution for PQ, and the reason why step-by-step iteration won't work, is because of PQ is not an incrementally sorted array under the hood.

Comment: we seem to be talking past each other at this point.  i fully understand why PQ is implemented the way that it is.  i think maybe we have different interpretations of the OP.  i think the OP has a bad assumption that PQ iteration would be ordered, which can be clarified by reading the javadocs.  i think that maybe you interpret the OP's question as confusion about why the implementation might behave a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

This is because PriorityQueue is an implementation of min heap (in Java by default), this means the root element will be always lower than the other elements in the list.

To take the example from your question:

1. When you insert 10, in the array the element at index 1 is 10
2. When you insert 1, as `1 < 10` the element at position 1 is now 1 and 10 it shifted to index 2
3. When you insert 2, as `1 < 2` there is no need to shift the element, and 2 is inserted at index 3
4. When you insert 2, the 2 will go under 10, as `10 > 2` a shift is needed, 2 is inserted at 2 and 10 is shited to the index 4

After all inserts the array looks like this, also check the video below:

```
array: [NULL, 1, 2, 2, 10]
```

[image]

Now when you remove 2, a shift is required for 10, and 10 is moved back to index 2, and the state of array is `[NULL, 1, 10, 2]` and this is what you see as the output when you iterate. Also, check [the following method](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/PriorityQueue.java#l651) that is implemented inside PriorityQueue and is used when you don't provide a `Comparator`.

```
private void siftUpComparable(int k, E x) {
    Comparable<? super E> key = (Comparable<? super E>) x;
    while (k > 0) {
        int parent = (k - 1) >>> 1;
        Object e = queue[parent];
        if (key.compareTo((E) e) >= 0)
            break;
        queue[k] = e;
        k = parent;
    }
    queue[k] = key;
}
```